# Display Datepicker Dialog box in extend in linear layout not activity

Tags: android, android-layout, datepicker

I am display UI using extend linear layout not activity from programmatically.like this

> public class DisplayDatePicker extends LinearLayout{
>
> Here is i want to display date picker by click button getDate; and
>   display on textview. }

```
Date = Calendar.getInstance();

    btnnTest.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                 showDateDialog(etTest, Date);
                            }

                        });
```

now expand above funtion showDateDialog, it call successfully but doesnot display datepicker dialog;

```
protected void showDateDialog(EditText etLocationTest2, Calendar date2) {
        Log.i("", "Date showDateDialog ");
     ((Activity) getContext()).showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

    }

In here Could not display Date picker Dialog box, why? i think showDialog box could not call DATE_DIALOG_ID,
so how to call this, any idea?
```

**Deatils of showDialog box here:**

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            // set date picker as current date
                    return new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), datePickerListener, year, month,day);
        return null;
    }



private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            year = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth;
            day = selectedDay;
            // set selected date into textview
            tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                    .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                    .append(" "));


        }
```

I hope you understand my problem, and waiting any response.

Comment: `showDateDialog` method is in Activity or in your non-Activity class??

Comment: not activity class. extended from linearlayout.

Comment: So there is context problem. You need to make constructor for `DisplayDatePicker`  class and use `Context` of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me. Hope it helps u too

I have added all the code to implements this in below

Save it in your class extending linearlayout

```
DatePopListener mDatePopListener;
private DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;
```

create a constructor getting context from where this class is initialsed.
Code used and it works fine for me.

```
class displayDatePicker extends linearlayout{
DatePopListener mDatePopListener;
EditText edittext;
TextBox label;
private DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;
public  displayDatePicker(Context context,String labelText){
dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);
Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
label.setText(labelText);
this.addView(label);
this.addView(txtBox);
txtBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          datePickerDialog.show();

        }
    });
    datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            txtBox.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
        }

    },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));


}
//Now you can do your task here whatever as the date will be available in txtBox
//Enter your code as your requirements
}
```